# Changing Button Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

In Form1 i have several buttons with a similar image on them to indicate a particular facility, let's say a tennis court. However let's say now i click on another button in another form to book that particular court, how can i change the button image on Form1 to another image, in order to show that it is booked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use events for that.

Booking action will fire an event that will indicate that a facility is booked.
Form1 will have an event handler registered to it and change the button's image to reflect the state of the facility.

**Edit** (how to do this with events):

```
public class FacilityStateChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public FacilityStateChangeEventArgs(bool booked)
    {
        this.Booked = booked;
    }

    public bool Booked { get; protected set; }
    // ... other properties if you need them
}

public class Facility
{
    private bool booked = false;
    public bool Booked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.booked;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (this.booked == value) return;


            // Changes the state and fires the event.
            this.booked = value;
            FireChange();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<FacilityStateChangeEventArgs> StateChange;

    // You will use this method when booked gets changed
    public void FireChange()
    {
        if (this.StateChange != null) this.StateChange(this, new FacilityStateChangeEventArgs(this.Booked));
    }
}

// The form with the image button.
public class FormWithButton
{
    Button button1 = new Button();

    public void Whatever()
    {
        // You will get the facility from your bussiness instances.
        Facility facility = new Facility();

        facility.StateChange += new EventHandler<FacilityStateChangeEventArgs>(facility_StateChange);
    }

    void facility_StateChange(object sender, FacilityStateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Booked) button1.Image = null; // booked image
        else button1.Image = null; // free image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i go about using this events and event handler?

Comment: @pacheco: I have added code to my answer 3 weeks ago, you may have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

change the image property of the button to show another resource. Eg/

```
   using namespace.Properties;

   namespace namespace
   {

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            button1.Image = Resources.pictureName;

         }
    }
```

You could save the information of whether that court is booked in the database and then return a picture depending on a bool field in the database.

EG
you have a database with a table called court, as such the fields are id(pk), name and isBooked(bool)

on page load you could have

```
      sqlconnection con = new sqlconnection("insert connstring here");
      sqlcommand com = new sqlcommand("select isBooked from court where id = @id", con);
      con.open();
      sqldatareader reader = com.executereader();
      while(reader.read())
      { 
          bool booked = (bool)reader["isBooked"];
      }


      if(booked = true)
          //one picture as above
      else
          //another picture
```

forgive me for sloppy code its just an example

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What if the button that i would like to change is in another form?

Comment: The database option is the best because the information would be taken from the db. Check out the edit ill put on the original post

Comment: Hi, i'm thinking of doing it through db, after you suggested it but i'm using OleDb though, how would the codes differ?

Comment: not sure not used oledb, i beleive it is just the sqlconnection/command and datareader etc changes to oledbsqlconnection but i have never used oledb so i cant really help sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok i assume you are launching the Booking Form from the Form1 where you are showing the button with Court. So the code will look somthing like this in the Form1  (Where you have that court image button):

```
FormBooking frm = new FormBooking();
frm.Controls["nameofbooking_button"].Click += (se,ev) =>{
            //The button with the court image
            CourtImageButton.Image = //Your new image
     }
frm.Show();
```

Now when that button will be clicked on the booking form you Court Image Button will change its image.

And if its 2005 that is .Net 2.0 so we have no lambda so here is the code:

```
FormBooking frm = new FormBooking();
frm.Controls["nameofbooking_button"].Click += new EventHandler(ChangeImage);
frm.Show();
```

then some where in your Form1 class:

```
private void ChangeImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //The button with the court image
            this.CourtImageButton.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\courtbooked.png");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How do i insert my image if let's say its called courtbooked.png in resources in the this.CourtImageButton.Image = ? statement?

Comment: I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: this line: frm.Controls["Court1Button"].Click += new EventHandler(ChangeImage);

Comment: make sure that Court1Button is the name of the Button and not the Instance name

Comment: On the designer right click on the button (Court1Button as mentioned) and select Properties. Then look for **name** it is the name that you should use in the specified answer. (Note that it should be the **exact** same name (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

simply use this if you are not communicating with database

Form one button Click for showing other form here form2

```
 Form2 frmtwo = new Form2(this);
  frmtwo.ShowDialog();
```

then in second form constructor add this

```
 Form Frmtwo;
        public Form2(Form frm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Frmtwo = frm;
        }
```

then add this code to the button click where you want to show image in first form

```
PictureBox pc = (PictureBox)Frmtwo.Controls["pictureBox1"];
pc.ImageLocation  = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\1.jpg";
```